# Adding a Menu Screen to an iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, view, menu

I'm working on a game application for the iPad and now that I've made the game work in a single view I wish to add an opening menu where a user can either go to the game or change the settings. How do you lay this out in xCode? Many thanks in advance from a puzzled programmer.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of ways of doing something like this.

Although Cocoa Touch has Action Sheets for menu-like selection, this isn't really a very common or good way to select subsequent views.  A Tab Bar type UI probably takes too much screen real estate for a game.  A UITableView would would be a generic UI for selecting subsequent views in a hierarchy, but it's not very game-like.

Look at the Utility app template built into XCode for iOS.  It shows how a button on one view can flip to another view.  You can easily modify this template to have two big image buttons to flip to two separate views.  That might get you started the most quickly with an interface that isn't too non-game-like.